# django-openid-auth OpenID failed : unknown user

Tags: python, django, django-openid-auth

I'm trying to implement a simple single sign on Open ID authentication on Steam via `django-openid-auth` using `Django 1.4.1`
I basically used the same exact settings as provided in the [official repo example](https://github.com/jezdez/django-openid-auth/blob/master/example_consumer/settings.py) :

```py
import os
import django
import settings_local

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)

ADMINS = (
     ('me', 'me@gmail.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': settings_local.DB_NAME,
        'USER': settings_local.DB_USER,
        'PASSWORD': settings_local.DB_PW,
        'HOST': settings_local.DB_HOST,
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Paris'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
SITE_ID = 1
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = ''

STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

SECRET_KEY = settings_local.PROJECT_SECRET_KEY

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "templates"),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'south',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'accounts',
    'django_openid_auth',
)

AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'accounts.UserProfile'

# django-debug-toolbar
INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1',)
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    'INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS': True,
    'SHOW_TEMPLATE_CONTEXT': True,
}

# django-openid-auth
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_openid_auth.auth.OpenIDBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

OPENID_CREATE_USER = True
#ALLOWED_EXTERNAL_OPENID_REDIRECT_DOMAINS = ['http://steamcommunity.com/']
OPENID_UPDATE_DETAILS_FROM_SREG = False
OPENID_SSO_SERVER_URL = settings_local.STEAM_OPENID_ENDPOINT
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
OPENID_USE_AS_ADMIN_LOGIN = False 

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        }
    }
```

my `views.py`

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render_to_response('home.html', {'username':
            request.openid})
    else:
        return render_to_response('home.html', {'auth_url': '/openid/login/'})

def next_works(request):
    return HttpResponse('?next= bit works')

@login_required
def require_authentication(request):
    return HttpReponse('This page requires authentication')

def login(request):
    pass
```

`home.html`

```html
<p>index</p>
{% if auth_url %}
<form action="{{ action }}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p> <a href={{ auth_url }}>log in</a></p>
    {% if username %}
    you are {{ username }}
    {% endif %}
</form>
{% endif %}
```

`runserver` log:

```
[18/Aug/2012 23:07:23] "GET /openid/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 152374
Error attempting to use stored discovery information: <openid.consumer.consumer.TypeURIMismatch: Required type http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/signon not found in ['http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/server'] for endpoint <openid.consumer.discover.OpenIDServiceEndpoint server_url='https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login' claimed_id=None local_id=None canonicalID=None used_yadis=True >>
Attempting discovery to verify endpoint
Performing discovery on http://steamcommunity.com/openid/id/XXXXXXX
Received id_res response from https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login using association 1234567890
Using OpenID check_authentication
signed
op_endpoint
claimed_id
identity
return_to
response_nonce
assoc_handle
[18/Aug/2012 23:07:34] "GET /openid/complete/?janrain_nonce=2012-08-18T21%3A07%3A23ZqVw9m0&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fsteamcommunity.com%2Fopenid%2Flogin&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fsteamcommunity.com%2Fopenid%2Fid%2FXXXXXXX&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fsteamcommunity.com%2Fopenid%2Fid%2FXXXXXXX&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%3A8000%2Fopenid%2Fcomplete%2F%3Fjanrain_nonce%3D2012-08-18T21%253A07%253A23ZqVw9m0&openid.response_nonce=2012-08-18T21%3A07%3A21Z1IUzhN7wFJy70hXK0bam4nlVxsc%3D&openid.assoc_handle=1234567890&openid.signed=signed%2Cop_endpoint%2Cclaimed_id%2Cidentity%2Creturn_to%2Cresponse_nonce%2Cassoc_handle&openid.sig=yvReb4BR0gTpkig0cLyT%2BA5QdYc%3D HTTP/1.1" 403 169466
```

What happens :

- user clicks on login
- redirected to steamcommunity.com/openid/login and asked steam id/pw
- redirected back to the website at `/openid/complete/?janrain_nonce=...` with a `403` error code, triggering `django-openid-auth` "unknown user" message code

What I have tried :

- using the `django-openid-auth` exemple and replacing `OPENID_SSO_SERVER_URL` by the Steam OpenID endpoint -- it works
- using this [exemple repository](https://github.com/rajasaur/openid_userprofiles/) and placing the Steam OpenID endpoint in `/media/js/openid-en.js` -- it works too

I can't find what is wrong in my code after searching for hours now.

EDIT : Fixed it.
Simply took `settings.py` from `django-openid-auth/example_consumer` and changed it line by line to see where the problem was. Ended up having the exact same `settings.py` pasted on this page but it's now working...

Comment: Can you post your fix as an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the exact same issue and discovered that the problem was with this line:

```
OPENID_CREATE_USER = True
```

This setting is missing the `S` at the end of the name.  The line should read:

```
OPENID_CREATE_USERS = True
```

Correcting this typo caused OpenID login to work perfectly.  When the OP says *"Ended up having the exact same `settings.py` pasted on this page but it's now working..."* they probably missed this very small difference.

Comment: I have "OPENID_CREATE_USERS = True" and still have 403 on that POST so yeah, it's not as simple as typo.